# Ubuntu 12.04 totally freezes while browsing or using VirtualBox

Tags: 12.04, freeze

My system:
 Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
 8GB memory
 Intel Core i3 540
 AMD ATI RV710 [Radeon HD 4350] - graphic driver

I have tried to figure out what is causing the freeze, but I have not found it. It typically happens when I browse in any browser to websites with flash content or are rich graphically. It also freezes when I use VirtualBox, and I have had a lot of difficulty installing different distros in VirtualBox. I have managed to install after tweaking VirtualBox, but it still freezes the whole system.

I have tried both to use the proprietary graphic driver and without using it, both ways it freezes.

When I was running Ubuntu 10.04 before, everything worked fine until after I installed Ubuntu 12.04. I have put more memory in between, but running memtest did not find any errors.

Regarding browsers, Chrome was the worst browser, so I have uninstalled it. Opera and Firefox still crash.

I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> - no response.
I have tried <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>REISUB</kbd> slowly - no response.
What happens is that the screen locks and there is no response from any device. The only way to get it running is to push the reset button on my computer.

It actually froze when I was using the Firefox spellchecker (right mouse click) on this question.

So how can I get a stable system? How can I find what is wrong and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a hardware issue, in particular the graphics card. This would at least explain why freezing occurs when you are using applications that require additional graphics processing.

Comment: I agree. the graphics card may be overheating. If it is possible to use the Intel's integrated graphics, and turn off the AMD card, try that. I don't have the steps of how to do that though. Hence this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: That's a drawback on my desktop, my mainboard doesn't have an integrated graphics. At least there is no display port except my graphic card on the back of my computer.

Comment: What graphic card would you recommend for ubuntu? I only need a cheap graphic card, no gaming or vidoe editing on the computer, only virtualbox and office work. Which mean I need a stable card that is well tested and works fine in ubuntu.

Comment: Without confining myself to specific models, I would look for a graphics card with an attached fan, not necessarily a huge fan, at least 1GB memory and 40nm or less GPU lithography. The driver updates for NVidia graphics cards seem to come to the Ubuntu Software Center sooner than the driver updates for AMD graphics cards. A lot of the new monitors use the HDMI port, so an HDMI port is a plus. There are a lot of cheap graphics cards out there that meet ALL of these specifications.

Comment: Please post if you wouldn't mind whether the new graphics card fixes the problem.  I have what sounds like a very similar issue, except that I have an nvidia card.  If it is the graphics card, how would one go about checking for that in the logs?  I don't see anything specific.

Comment: I have now changed my graphic card to Nvidia Geforce GT610 with fan. So far so good. No freeze after 1 hour of use. Browser and virtualbox works fine. I'll come back with comment after more testing.

Comment: It solved my initial question. My computer doesn't freeze anymore during use. I have tried heavy browsing with several pages up at the same time and been looking at flash content at the same time as virtualbox is running. No freeze there. The only time it has froze, is when installing a new virtual os - which is a virtualbox settings. So this solved my problem. :D